# Exibir dados relacionados durante Iteração

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Criei um relacionamento entre os models `client` e `content` e consigo acessar os respectivos dados usando o `console` normalmente.

```
con = Content.find(1)
con.client.name # Nome do cliente
```

Porém quando tento acessr esses dados durante um loop, recebo o erro que o `name` não foi definido/não existe.

```
@content = Content.all
@content.each do |content| 
   puts content.title
   puts content.target
   puts content.client.name # O erro acontece aqui
```

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá @Rafael,

Problema é que no registro que buscou no console `client` existe, mas durante o loop um dos registros não tem um `client` relacionado gerando erro. Existem diversos modos para resolver um deles é utilizar o `try` (para versões anteriores ao `ruby 2.3` :

```
@content = Content.all
@content.each do |content| 
   puts content.title
   puts content.target
   puts content.client.try(:name)
end
```

Ou para as versões superiores ao `2.3`, um modo ainda mais limpo, usando o `Safe Navigation Operator (&.)` :

```
@content = Content.all
@content.each do |content| 
   puts content.title
   puts content.target
   puts content.client&.name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro define explicitamente que `content.client` não é inicializado.

Como foi criado o relacionamento ?

Nesse caso:
client belongs_to content
e:
content has_one client

E nas migrations mapear o recurso referenciado.

fonte:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: o `client` `has_many` contents e o `contents` `belongs_to` clients

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro significa que a classe **nil** não contém o método **name**. Isso se dá porque algum(s) dos seus **content** não tem client associado, logo **content.client** retorna nil, e **content.client.name** retorna o erro informado porque vc está tentando usar o método **name** na classe **nil**.

Se não for possível forçar para que todos os **contents** tenham **clients**, o ideal é verificar para cada registro se **client** existe antes de tentar usar **name**. Um exemplo:

```
puts content.client.name if content.client
```